# Cofigure ipdb for eclipse PyDev

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, pdb

Basic version of pdb works just fine, but I really like iPython so I want to get myself ipdb too, but I encountered some problems while running in a PyDev project.

I put following line in my program :

```
...
import ipdb;ipdb.set_trace()
...
```

I am getting following output :

```
import ipdb;ipdb.set_trace()
ImportError: No module named ipdb
```

I've installed ipdb via pip ( I prefer pip to easy_install, because of uninstall option ).

```
Jakubs-MacBook-Pro:experiments Kuba$ pip install ipdb
Downloading/unpacking ipdb
  Downloading ipdb-0.7.tar.gz
  Running setup.py egg_info for package ipdb

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): ipython>=0.10 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from ipdb)
Installing collected packages: ipdb
  Running setup.py install for ipdb

Installing ipdb script to /usr/local/share/python
Successfully installed ipdb
Cleaning up...
Jakubs-MacBook-Pro:experiments Kuba$ cd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Jakubs-MacBook-Pro:site-packages Kuba$ cd ipdb
Jakubs-MacBook-Pro:ipdb Kuba$ ls
__init__.py  __init__.pyc __main__.py  __main__.pyc
```

In Eclipse I added this path to python interpreter's System PYTHONPATH:

```
System libs -> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipdb
```

Then I restarted Eclipse and excpected it work, but it doesn't.

When I go to Project->Properties-> PyDev -> Interpreter -> "Click here to configure interpreter" -> Then I choosed the one I want to use, this path is included :

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipdb
```

in System PYTHONPATH.

[image: project properties]

However if I open Properties window on single python module within this project it looks a bit diffrent :

Properties on certain module -> Run/Debug Settings -> Launch config -> Edit -> "Main" Tab

PYTHONPATH that will be used in the run:

```
...
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipdb
```

But in the "Interpreter" Tab - the default interpreter is chosen instead of the one I wanted to use, even if I change it after run it still doesn't work and it switches back to default interpreter.

[image: module properties]

Something's wrong here, but I have no clue what..

Can anyone help and say how to get ipdb working with PyDev?

EDIT:

Content of sys.path :

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/560/syspathscreen.png/

Comment: what are the results if you run import sys; print sys.path? are you sure it installed ipdb for python2.7?

Comment: I edited the post. Click the link at the bottom of the post to see the content of syspath.

Comment: I surrender. I installed pdbpp instead.

Comment: sorry for overlooking the pydev window, the path you needed to add was /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/, i assumed it was already there